# É possível acessar uma Web Api pelo Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, winforms, api, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

Desenvolvi uma Api que se comunica com meu banco de dados e a coloquei no IIS. Testando em aplicações Windows Forms, a busca dos dados da api funciona normalmente, porém quando tento executá-la dentro do app Windows Phone retorna o erro a seguir:

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d(Object sendState) at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object sendState) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state) at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)}

Porquê o erro está ocorrendo? Eu testo o app pelo próprio emulador do Visual Studio 2013, será que é necessário desabilitar algum firewall ou fazer alguma configuração especial?

Answer (score 0):

Este erro NotFound é um erro bem mais genérico do que voce pensa. Ele pode ocorrer quando a API realmente não existe, ou existe mas retorna o status code incorreto ou, o que eu acho mais comum, quando dá algum erro devido a proxy.

Eu tenho aplicativos na loja do WindowsPhone que consomem WebApi. Uma vez que voce tenha certeza que não é problema de proxy, firewall, etc., o código abaixo funciona perfeitamente em minha aplicação.

Obs:

1 - Minha app é Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

2 - Sempre que possível teste seus Apps direto no seu aparelho

```
try
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();

    // A minha WebApi implementa um DelegatingHandler para autenticação customizada
    // Por isso passo o usuario e senha.
    // Se a sua nao tiver, basta comentar a linha abaixo.
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Usuario", "Senha");

    // Progresso do download do arquivo
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Label com o total de bytes ja baixado. Tipo: 200 de 5000, 300 de 5000, etc...
            lblDownloadStatus.Text = "Baixado " + GetFileSize(e.BytesReceived) + "/" + GetFileSize(e.TotalBytesToReceive);

            // Percentual baixado. Tipo: 5%... 10%... etc...
            lblPercentual.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
        });
    };

    // Fim do processo de download do arquivo. Agora é só tratar o que voce quiser.
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                Minha_Funcao_Para_Tratar_O_Stream_Baixado(e.Result);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            string erro = e.Error.Message;
            if (erro.ToString().Contains("not found"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível realizar o download do arquivo. Por favor, verifique as configurações da sua internet e tente novamente.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao baixar arquivo: " + erro);
            }
        }
    };

    // Abre e executa a URL.
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.suaapi.com/DownloadArquivo"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Estás a usar localhost? Não podes, mesmo a testar pelo emulador. Tens que trocar o localhost pelo IP da máquina.